# Compile project code and then generate apk online

Tags: android

hello，i want to put my project code and Sdk ,and so on to internet,.then someone can get my project apk by using the code. i want to some advice and some clue. because many people can get my new apk,and i donot want to directly give apk to people。

Comment: i think you need some kind of cruise control tool which is continuous integration tool.

Answer (score 0):

Use [www.github.com](http://www.github.com) for Source Code and [www.travis-ci.org](http://travis-ci.org) for Continuos Integrations